# PostgreSQL How to get the rows that has two or more columns that meets the same condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, combinations, where-clause

I need to have the rows that has two or more columns that meets the same condition.
Something like this:

```
id | column1 | column2 | column3
--------------------------------
1  | 'yes'   | 'yes'   |  'yes'
2  | 'yes'   | 'yes'   |  'no'
3  | 'yes'   | 'no'    |  'no'
4  | 'no'    | 'no'    |  'no'
5  | 'yes'   | 'no'    |  'yes'
6  | 'no'    | 'yes'   |  'yes'
```

So, I need to perform a SELECT clause that returns the rows with id 1,2,5,6
Doing it one by one AND/OR combination it would result in a very large clause (**there are actually 8 columns**).
Is it any other faster way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that relies on Postgres ability to understand conditions as booleans, then as integers:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (column1 = 'yes')::int 
    + (column2 = 'yes')::int 
    + (column3 = 'yes')::int >= 2
```

You might also want to consider a lateral join: that's a bit longer to type to start with, but easier to scale.

```
select t.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral ( 
    select count(*) cnt
    from (values (column1), (column2), (column3)) x(col)
    where x.col = 'true'
) x
where x.cnt >= 2
```

Comment: At first look apparently solves my problem! Thank you very much. I was all afternoon looking up for something like this,